# Misunderstanding of Lebesgue Theorem

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Let $\varphi\in\text{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\varphi\ge 0$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi(x)\; dx=1$ and define for $\varepsilon > 0$ $$\varphi_{\varepsilon}(x)=\varepsilon^{-n}\varphi(\varepsilon^{-1}x).$$ I must prove that $$\forall\delta>0\quad\int_{\lVert x\rVert\ge\delta}\varphi_{\varepsilon}(x)\;dx\to 0\;\text{for}\;\varepsilon\to 0^+$$

With the change of variable $\color{red}{y=\varepsilon^{-1}x}$ we have $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi_{\epsilon}(x)\;dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\varphi(y)\;dy=1.$$

Also you have  $$\int_{\lVert x\rVert\ge \delta}\varphi_{\epsilon}(x)\; dx=\color{blue}{\int_{\lVert y\rVert\ge \varepsilon\delta}\varphi(y)\; dy\to 0\;\text{for}\;\varepsilon\to 0}$$

> I know that the part in blue is true for the Lebesgue Theorem (Dominated Convergence), but I don't understand how it was used, are the hypotheses of this theorem verified? Could someone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: By Lebesgue Theorem, do you mean the Dominated (or Monotone) Convergence Theorem?  Something else?

Perhaps even more importantly, is the challenge to verify that the integral of $\phi(y)$ is defined on the indicated domains (i.e., outside of the disc $||y|| \geq \delta \epsilon$?  If so, use the function $I_{r}(y)$, equal to 1 for $||y|| < r$ and 0 otherwise.  It is measurable and Lebesgue-integrable.  So is the product $\phi(y) I_{r}(y)$ for all nonnegative $r$.

Now,
$$
\int_{||y|| \geq \epsilon \delta} \phi(y) dy = 1 - \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \phi(y) I_{\epsilon \delta}(y) dy.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tiny mistake in your change of variables. It should be
$$\int_{\lVert x\rVert\ge \delta}\varphi_{\epsilon}(x)\; dx=
\int\varepsilon^{-n}\phi(x/\varepsilon)\mathbb{1}_{B^c(0;\delta)}(\varepsilon x/\varepsilon)\,dx= \color{blue}{\int_{\lVert y\rVert\ge \varepsilon^{-1}\delta}\varphi(y)\; dy}$$

Then, the point is that

$f_\varepsilon(y):=\mathbb{1}_{B^c(0;\epsilon^{-1}\delta)}(y)\phi(y)$

is dominated by $\phi$, and that $\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}f_\varepsilon(x)=0$ for almost all $x$ (in fact for all $x$ in the OP's case).